# Analyze the logical forms of the following statements?

Tags: logic

Analyze the logical forms of the following statements:
3 is a common divisor of 6, 9, and 15.

Is my solution correct?

Let f(x) stand for 3 is a common divisor of x

f(6) && f(9) && f(15)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Or maybe this one, 3mod(6) = 0 && 3mod(9) = 0 && 3mod(15) = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let $f(x)$ stand for 3 is a common divisor of $x$" is unhappy twice over.

First, you must mean "3 is a divisor of $x$" -- 3 can't be a common divisor of just one number: you are a common devisor of some numbers, plural!!

Second, $f$ is standardly a function expression, and what is defined here isn't a function but a property, the property $x$ has when divisible by $3$. So you need a predicate expression.

So you could use the one-place predicate $P$, where $Px$ stands for 3 is a divisor of $x$, and then the original statement can be rendered $P(6) \land P(9) \land P(15)$ -- with bracketing if you want to be fussy.

Or depending on context, you might prefer to use the two-place predicate $R$ where $R(x,y)$ means that $x$ divides $y$, and then render the original statement $R(3,6) \land R(3,9) \land R(3,15)$.

There's no context-free right answer about which of those gives "the" logical form (there is no such thing).

Comment: Yes now it makes sense about the "common"/for plurals only part, I must excuse myself, I am not from an English speaking country, so I am doing my best in trying to learn mathematics in English! :) But thanks, you helped me with the solution.